# Image not uploaded from angular to Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5.1

I am created a form for save items details with the image.I am using laravel 5.1 and angularJS. The items information will be saved succesfully but the image not uploaded to server and also image details not saved in database.I need help to upload image into laravel using angularjs

Its my HTML Code:

```
    <div ng-controller="itemController">
<form ng-submit="addItem()">
    <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" value="" ng-model="newitem.name" placeholder="Item Name">
    <label>Model No:</label><input type="text" name="model" value="" ng-model="newitem.model" placeholder="Model Number">
    <label>Size:</label><input type="text" name="size" value="" ng-model="newitem.size" placeholder="Item Size">
    <label>Colour:</label><input type="text" name="color" value="" ng-model="newitem.color" placeholder="Item Colour">
    <br>
    <label>Description:</label><textarea cols="30" rows="5" ng-model="newitem.description" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
    <br>
    <label>Photo:</label><input type="file"  accept="imag/works" ngf-select="" ngf-multiple="true"  class="form-control" id="img" name="img" placeholder="Image" ng-model="newitem.photo" multiple>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
<div ng-show="sendmessage">
    Item Saved Successfully...........
</div>

<div>
```

AngularJs Code:

```
app.controller('itemController',function($scope,$http,Item) {
$scope.items=[];
$scope.newitem={};
$scope.curitem = {};
$scope.sendmessage=false;

loadData();

//To Send Message to Site Admin..................

$scope.addItem=function(){
    if($scope.curitem.id){
        //TODO error display
        $scope.newitem.$update(function () {
            angular.extend($scope.curitem,$scope.curitem, $scope.newitem);
            $scope.sendmessage=true;
        });
    }else{
        $scope.newitem.$save(function (item) {
            //TODO error display
            $scope.items.push(item);
            $scope.sendmessage=true;
        });
    }
    //$scope.sendmessage=true;
    $scope.curitem = {};
    $scope.newitem = {};
    $scope.newitem=new Item();
    loadData();
};



function loadData(){
    var items =Item.query(function () {
        $scope.items = items;
        $scope.newitem=new Item();
    });
}
});


angular.module('ItemService',[]).factory('Item',['$resource',
function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/items/:itemId',{
        itemId:'@id'
    },{
        update:{
            method:'PUT'
        }
    });
}
]);
```

ItemController.php is given below...

```
        <?php

        namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

        use App\File;
        use App\Item;
        use Illuminate\Http\Request as Request;
        use App\Http\Requests;
        use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
        use Illuminate\Http\Response;
        use Validator;
        use Input;

       class ItemController extends Controller
       {
              /**
             * Validates given data for account
 * @param array $data
 * @return Validator
 */

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    // Loan account is not validated

    return Validator::make($data,[
        'name'  => 'required',
        'size'   => 'required|max:255'
    ]);

}


/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
    if($validator->fails()){
        return Response::json( $validator->errors()
            ,400);
    }
    $item=new Item($request->all());
    if($item->save())
    {
        $id=$item->id;
        if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
            $file = $request->file('photo');
            $image=new File();
            $image->name = $this->uploadImage($file);
            $image->file_id=$id;
            $image->save();
        }
    }

    return Response::json(['error' => 'Server is down']
        ,500);
}


/**
 * To Strore Images
 *
 *
 */

public  function uploadImage($file){

        $storedFileName="";
        if(!empty($file)){

            $extension=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension;
            $storedFileName=base_path().'/img/works/'. $fileName;
            $file->move(
                base_path().'/img/works/', $fileName
            );
        }
    return $storedFileName;
}


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For uploading images via AngularJS, you need to do little extra work. You can either use some library like [nervgh/angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload) (or some other library) or do it yourself. For further reference watch [this tutorial by egghead](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-file-uploads)